# issues while doing deployment of war file and doing configuration of mariadb into wildfly 18.0.0 FInal

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-11, wildfly-18, jboss-wildfly-11

I have added the module.xml file and appropriate mariadb connector jar files, in wildfly/module/.../com/maraidb. I have added the Jar visa console also but when the execute standalone.sh file i get these errors which i am not sure about.

```
 11:46:22,822 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "browserconfig.xml")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"browserconfig.xml\".\"browserconfig.xml\".DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS]"]
}
```

Comment: Did you created your datasource ? Is it working ? Could you share your configuration ?

Comment: @ehsavoie, i  have added my standalone.xml file can you please check once if i am right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have an extra file browserconfig.xml which I deleted and it worked.
Followed the below-mentioned links and made the adjustments in standalone.xml
https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBEAP-2405
```